# Same instance of database with same data is too slow postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I use Postgresql v12.11 for my application

Now I have performance issue in a table with 4M rows of data.

I export my database and create new postgresql container with same version and same memory and cpu.
when I tested the queries that take long in my new instance it answer 10 times faster with out any performance issue.

also the first instanse that is slow has no other connection to app that run query on it.

I run really simple query like this.

```sql
SELECT COUTN(*) FROM my_table WHERE host='www.example.com';
```

the host column is a index and I set the hash as method

for each test I clear cache to make sure they do not using cache.
but in the first instance it takes 90s -> after 10 times without clear cache it takes 40s
and in second instance it takes 3s -> after 10 times without clear cache it takes 1.32ms

I run reindex and vacuum for the table that I have in slower instance

but nothing changes.

what else should I do.

Comment: Did you say you have a HASH, rather than BTREE, index on that column? To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. It may also help us if you give us some specs (RAM, IO) on your host machines and containers.  Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Maybe the original table is very bloated. A regular VACUUM or a reindex will not fix that, you need to VACUUM FULL, or something else which rewrites the entire table (like a dump and re-import).  Just looking at the size of the table between the two systems should indicate if this is the case.

Comment: As mentioned, most likely you're suffering from bloat and/or fragmentation. Either run VACUUM FULL on the tables involved or, if you can take the db offline long enough, take a backup and restore said backup again; that should bring the original env in the same state as your test env.